# Probability of a gaussian distribution in another gaussian distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Assume we have a Gaussian distribution $p(x) \sim  \mathcal{N}(\mu_p,\Sigma_p)$

For any point $X$, it is easy to compute the density of $x$ in $p$:
$$p(x) = \frac{1}{|2\pi \Sigma_p|^\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_p)^T\Sigma_p^{-1}(x-\mu_p)}$$

[image]

Now suppose that we have another Gaussian distribution  $q(x) \sim  \mathcal{N}(\mu_q,\Sigma_q)$

** What is the expectation of q(x) in p(x) **. I mean, if we randomly sample a point $x$ from P, what is the **expected probability** of x in Q?

[image]

**NOTE:** I need the solution in closed form.

Thanks!

Comment: The right side of $$p(x) = \frac{1}{|2\pi \Sigma_i|^\frac{-1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma_i^{-1}(x-\mu)}dx$$ is **not** "the **probability** of $x$ in $p$" but the value of the _density_ of a bivariate normal random variable at $x$ (and the density value might well exceed $1$). In  "If we randomly sample a point $x$ from (a different bivariate normal distribution) $Q$" there is no such thing as the "expected probability of $x$ in $P$": the value of the density (assuming the distribution is $P$) at $x$ does _not_ depend on how $x$ was chosen, e.g. with distribution $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in this case we will have:

$$E_{x\sim p(x)}[q(x)]=E_{x\sim q(x)}[p(x)]=\int_{x\in \mathcal{X}} p(x)q(x)dx$$
$$=\int_{x\in \mathcal{X}} \left(\frac{1}{|2\pi \Sigma_p|^\frac{-1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_p)^T\Sigma_p^{-1}(x-\mu_p)}\right)\left(\frac{1}{|2\pi \Sigma_q|^\frac{-1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_q)^T\Sigma_q^{-1}(x-\mu_q)}\right)dx$$

$$=\int_{x\in \mathcal{X}} \frac{1}{|2\pi \Sigma_p|^\frac{-1}{2}|2\pi \Sigma_q|^\frac{-1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left((x-\mu_p)^T\Sigma_p^{-1}(x-\mu_p)+(x-\mu_q)^T\Sigma_q^{-1}(x-\mu_q)\right)}dx$$

Now go ahead and, expand $(x-\mu_p)^T\Sigma_p^{-1}(x-\mu_p)+(x-\mu_q)^T\Sigma_q^{-1}(x-\mu_q)$ and regroup the the terms to get:
 $$(x-\mu_p)^T\Sigma_p^{-1}(x-\mu_p)+(x-\mu_q)^T\Sigma_q^{-1}(x-\mu_q)=x^TAx+b^Tx+d$$

Then work out the algebra to get $\Sigma$ and $\mu$ such that:

$$x^TAx+b^Tx+d=(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)+F$$

After this you will have some thing like this:

$$E_{x\sim q(x)}[p(x)]=\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{2}F} |2\pi \Sigma|^\frac{-1}{2}}{|2\pi \Sigma_p|^\frac{-1}{2}|2\pi \Sigma_q|^\frac{-1}{2}} \int_{x\in \mathcal{X}}\frac{1}{|2\pi \Sigma|^\frac{-1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}dx$$

$\int_{x\in \mathcal{X}}\frac{1}{|2\pi \Sigma|^\frac{-1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}dx=1$, so you'll have:

$$E_{x\sim q(x)}[p(x)]=\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{2}F} |2\pi \Sigma|^\frac{-1}{2}}{|2\pi \Sigma_p|^\frac{-1}{2}|2\pi \Sigma_q|^\frac{-1}{2}} $$

**Edit**

$$(x-\mu_p)^T\Sigma_p^{-1}(x-\mu_p)+(x-\mu_q)^T\Sigma_q^{-1}(x-\mu_q)=x^T(\Sigma_p^{-1}+\Sigma_q^{-1})x+(-2\mu_p^T\Sigma_p^{-1}-2\mu_q^T\Sigma_q^{-1})x+(\mu_p^T\Sigma_p^{-1}\mu_p+\mu_q^T\Sigma_q^{-1}\mu_q)$$

Let $A=\Sigma_p^{-1}+\Sigma_q^{-1}$,$b=(-2\mu_p^T\Sigma_p^{-1}-2\mu_q^T\Sigma_q^{-1})^T$, and $d=\mu_p^T\Sigma_p^{-1}\mu_p+\mu_q^T\Sigma_q^{-1}\mu_q$.

Now we should find $\Sigma$, $\mu$, and $F$, we have :

$$(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)=x^T\Sigma x-2\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}x+\mu^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu $$

Let:
$$x^TAx+b^Tx+d=x^T\Sigma^{-1} x-2\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}x+\mu^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu +F$$

$$\Sigma^{-1}=A=\Sigma_p^{-1}+\Sigma_q^{-1}\Rightarrow \Sigma=\left(\Sigma_p^{-1}+\Sigma_q^{-1}\right)^{-1}$$

$$b^{T}=-2\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\Rightarrow \mu=-\frac{1}{2}\Sigma b=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\Sigma_p^{-1}+\Sigma_q^{-1}\right)^{-1} (-2\mu_p^T\Sigma_p^{-1}-2\mu_q^T\Sigma_q^{-1})^T$$

$$\Rightarrow \mu=\left(\Sigma_p^{-1}+\Sigma_q^{-1}\right)^{-1} (\Sigma_p^{-1}\mu_p+\Sigma_q^{-1}\mu_q)$$

$$F=d-\mu^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu$$
$$\Rightarrow F=\mu_p^T\Sigma_p^{-1}\mu_p+\mu_q^T\Sigma_q^{-1}\mu_q-\mu^T \Sigma^{-1} \mu$$

$$E_{x\sim q(x)}[p(x)]=\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{2}F} |2\pi \Sigma|^\frac{-1}{2}}{|2\pi \Sigma_p|^\frac{-1}{2}|2\pi \Sigma_q|^\frac{-1}{2}} $$

Note that, the result is just an scalar, please let me know if you have further questions :)

Comment: ... So you mean there is no way to compute the expected probability in a simple formula?
(It seems that we need an equation-solver program for this?)

Comment: $${ (x-\mu_p)^T\Sigma_p^{-1}(x-\mu_p)+(x-\mu_q)^T\Sigma_q^{-1}(x-\mu_q) } $$
$$= x^T (\Sigma_p^{-1} + \Sigma_q^{-1})x 
    -2  ( \mu_p^T \Sigma_p^{-1}+\mu_q^T \Sigma_q^{-1}) x
    +  \left(    \mu_p^T \Sigma_p^{-1}\mu_p +  \mu_q^T \Sigma_q^{-1}\mu_q    \right)
$$  
so we have:
$$A=\Sigma_p^{-1} + \Sigma_q^{-1}$$
$$b^T = -2  ( \mu_p^T \Sigma_p^{-1}+\mu_q^T \Sigma_q^{-1})$$
$$d= \mu_p^T \Sigma_p^{-1}\mu_p +  \mu_q^T \Sigma_q^{-1}\mu_q$$
How should I extract $\Sigma$ and $\mu$ from A,b,c???

Comment: now expand $(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)+F$ and set it equal to $x^TAx+b^Tx+d$, find out what $\mu$, $\Sigma^{-1}$, and $F$, must be :) (Note that $-2\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}=b^T$ implies $\mu^T=-\frac{1}{2}b^T\Sigma$, and $\mu=-\frac{1}{2}\Sigma b$)

Comment: Oh, here is the problem: 
It is obvious that 
$$\Sigma^{-1} = \Sigma_p^{-1} + \Sigma_q^{-1}$$
However: 
$$ \mu^T \Sigma^{-1} = \mu^T (\Sigma_p^{-1} + \Sigma_q^{-1})  = \mu_p^T \Sigma_p^{-1}+\mu_q^T \Sigma_q^{-1} $$
As far as I know the algebra of matrices, It is not possible to compute $\mu$

Comment: @Alt: There is something wrong in the formula: First, it is forgotten to multiply $F$ by $\frac{-1}{2}$, so the result is 
$$
E_{x\sim q(x)}[p(x)]=\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{2} F} |2\pi \Sigma|^\frac{-1}{2}}{|2\pi \Sigma_p|^\frac{-1}{2}|2\pi \Sigma_q|^\frac{-1}{2}}
$$
. Second, the formula does not work (the predictions are wrong, according to the matlab simultions). I have no idea why!
Please check out this code:

http://www.alihadian.ir/Files/normtest.zip

Comment: @Alt: I found the typo. Now it works! We may correct the formula by replacing
$$\frac{1}{|2\pi \Sigma|^\frac{-1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}$$
with 
$$\frac{1}{|2\pi \Sigma|^\frac{+1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}dx$$

Hence the final solution would be:

$$E_{x\sim q(x)}[p(x)]=\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{2}F} |2\pi \Sigma|^\frac{+1}{2}}{|2\pi \Sigma_p|^\frac{+1}{2}|2\pi \Sigma_q|^\frac{+1}{2}}$$
I'll edit the solution today. Thanks again :)